# iterate stdClass in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am building a user edit form. I have a single user info. I want to iterate over it and get values. The array contains values I am fetching from the database in model and sending to view.php through controller. But how to iterate pver it in view.php ?

error :"**Message: Trying to get property of non-object**"

I am trying to get as `$results->first_name`

```
Array (
  [0] => stdClass Object (
    [id] => 15
    [first_name] => sachin
    [last_name] => sood
    [username] => sachin
    [email] => sachinsood91@gmail.com
    [password] => 202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
    [confirm_pass] => 123
    [status] => 0
  )
)
```

**Controller**

```
$this->load->model('User');
$row['results'] = $this->User->get_info($id);
$this->load->view('User/User_sign_up', $row);
```

**Model:**

```
$query= $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id));
return $query->result();
```

Comment: Post your controller code

Comment: updates ..please check.

Comment: `$results` looks like an array of objects. Have you tried `$results[0]->first_name` ?

Comment: +1 @LeGEC ... make this ans .. need to give you +1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your view to access first_name

```
   $results[0]->first_name
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, although Sudz code will indeed work, if you're just expecting a single user out (which given that you're where'ing by user_id, you are), the proper way of doing it in CodeIgniter would be changing your model to use row instead of result like so:

```
$query= $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id));
return $query->row();
```

Which would allow you to pull out directly as:

```
$results->first_name
```